# SelectedItem is not visually highlighted when set programmatically

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am using silverlight 4 listbox control to display list of terms, On selection of one term, I am calling an ria service to 
fetch similar words for that term and loading those similar terms for the other listbox. for one requirement I need to auto 
fetch the similar terms for the default or the first term in the terms listbox. I am achieving the same by selecting the 
first item of the itemsource although I have one issue where when I am programmatically setting the listbox selecteditem, 
its getting set, however visually the selected item is not getting highlighted. Any Ideas why the selected item is not 
getting highlighted when set programmatically.

The items change when I hover over them for the terms listbox.

note: I have attached one poc app demonstrating the above issue, when I run the poc app the similar terms for the first
term in the terms listbox are displayed. however the first item in this case "red" is not visually highlighted, when I click
the terms listbox for the UI the first item shows surronded by a transparent rectangle.

Things I have tried thing

I have used the VSM for specifying the SelectedUnfocused state for the ListboxItem Style and applied that style to the
itemcontainerstyle property of the listboxItem.

Comment: Could you show some code? Do you fire the PropertyChanged event after setting the bounded property?

Comment: Most likely you are using a *different instance* of the type.  In order for it to hook up automatically, the SelectedItem instance must exist within the ItemsSource collection.

Answer (score 1):

> however visually the selected item is not getting highlighted.

Call `ListBox.focus();`

Then programmatically select the item you want by either of these:

```
ListBox.SelectedItem = item;
ListBox.SelectedIndex = index;
ListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
etc.
```